# Deleting numbers that cancel each other out in a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this huge database in which there are some budget transfers that, when looking at the grand total, cancel each other out. Problem is, I can't seem to understand how I can delete all the rows that cancel each other out. The dataframe below works as an example:

`test = pd.DataFrame(data = [1050.77, 13.45, 6.26, -1050.77, 10027, 6.26, 13.45, 13.45, -13.45, -6.26, -16800, 16800], columns = ['Test'])`

```
    Test
0   1050.77
1   13.45
2   6.26
3   -1050.77
4   10027
5   6.26
6   13.45
7   13.45
8   -13.45
9   -6.26
10  -16800
11  16800
```

The Sum above is 10060.16

As you can see, the following numbers cancel each other out:

```
0   1050.77
3   -1050.77

1   13.45
8   -13.45

2   6.26
9   -6.26

10  -16800
11  16800
```

Therefore, the desired output is:

```
   Test
4   10027
5   6.26
6   13.45
7   13.45
```

and of course, the Sum above is 10060.16.

I've tried many things and I can't get it to work. The code below is one of the attempts that I made that don't work:

```
for idx1, i in enumerate(test['Test']):
    for idx2, j in enumerate(test['Test']):
        if (i + j == 0):
            test.drop(index = idx1, inplace = True)
            test.drop(index = idx2, inplace = True)            
test
```

I can either delete the number that is cancelling the other and then use dropna to eliminate the empty rows or, the best result, delete the entire row that the number has a "canceller"

I do not care about the index, it can be changed in any way.

The goal is to eliminate only the perfect matches of + and - numbers.

Edits: I've edited the DataFrame so it carries some floats

Any help on how to program this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this? You have 2 rows of `2` which would also cancel with the `-4`. So you consider only exact matches of numbers cancelling out?

Comment: In the real database, the numbers have decimals and can't be summed like that. This one here is just an example. 

What I am doing in the real database is a machine learning algorithm to predict the budget for the next year withouth consulting each department, but those budget transfers with negative values screw the algorithm. 

The goal is to eliminate the exact matches (- and +) of the numbers

Comment: If they have decimals then you'll also struggle to match them due to floating-point error. That would be an important detail in your [mcve] because it will likely cause issues with answers to your example as-given

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter without shift, I was going to write a bit more. I edited the answer above.

Comment: With your edited comment, I think you have an XY problem. You don't want to cancel them out, you are having issues with floating point rounding IIRC. You need to set a tolerance on what precision should be considered when evaluating whether two floats are equal

Comment: I can edit it and put some real data from the database

Comment: I think you will need to apply logic to window functions to get rid of those rows that cancel out.

Comment: Sure. As a side note; it's nice that you've gone to the effort to put together a minimal example for your first question :) Unfortunately, in this case, I think it masks your actual issue

Comment: Thanks for the compliment and thanks for the tips! I've edited the original post with some float values.

But as I execute the little code I've put there, it can't find some indexes and the code stops.

In my head it all makes sense, but python doesn't understand me =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid modifying lists while iterating through them. Instead create a list of indexes to drop and drop them after you have found them all. Also to avoid double dropping you need to break when you find a match and continue past things you have already marked to be dropped.

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(data = [3, 2, -4, 2, -3, 3, 2, 6, 7, 5, -6, 6, 3, 3, 4, 4], columns = ['Test'])

dropped = []

for idx1, i in enumerate(test['Test']):
    if idx1 in dropped:
        continue
    for idx2, j in enumerate(test['Test']):
        if idx2 in dropped or idx1 == idx2:
            continue
        if (i + j == 0):
            dropped += [idx1,idx2]
            break
for k in dropped:
    test.drop(index = k, inplace = True)
print(test)
```

Comment: This is a Series object. They shouldn't be iterating in the first place